# Bitbucket 5.0.0 is not compatible with git 2.14.0

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have updated git client from `2.13.3.windows.1` to `2.14.0.windows.1` recently. After this, I can no longer successfully execute any git command to the repository hosted by an on-premise Bitbucket 5.0 server instance, eg.:

```
$ git pull
Bitbucket cannot not execute "git upload-pack '/best/[redacted].git'". The command is not supported as entered.

Ensure you are using a supported SCM, check the syntax and try again.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

At the moment the only solution to overcome the problem is to downgrade back to git `2.13.3.windows.1`.

**How can I fix this to be able to use the latest git client with Bitbucket 5.0?**

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but upgrading Bitbucket server is probably a good idea. I suggest, at minimum, upgrading to the latest patch release for version 5.0, which [appears to be 5.0.6 at the time of writing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-5-0-release-notes-889528342.html). The latest 5.x release [appears to be Bitbucket Server 5.2.2 at the time of writing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-5-2-release-notes-917966093.html).

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Although it seems to be the simplest solution the Bitbucket server is used by the corporate company so an upgrade is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit2** [Git for windows 2.14.0.windows2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.0.windows.2) has been released fixing this issue.

**Edit:** As explained in the [related Bitbucket Server issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10013?focusedCommentId=1579887&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1579887), it's a Git For Windows issue. The change that caused the bug was reverted.
See https://git.io/v7KIb

The good move is to downgrade to Git 2.13 for now, and wait for a 2.14.1 bugfix release.

**Original answer:**

This may be a bug in Bitbucket Server 5. Some issues have been created on [Atlassian's Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10011?jql=text%20~%20%22git%202.14%22) regarding this error. As an example, [BSERV-10011](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10011) and [BSERV-10013](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10013) were both created a few hours ago.

You should wait for a Bitbucker Server update.

Comment: Will be fixed in Git see https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/0f3342804fc6fa558a7c9e220e7e9ab4c86e8226 and https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1258

Comment: Good to know. So the same error appear when connectiing to another servers (github, gitlab, gogs, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

Hello you can download second version with bugfix here: https://git-for-windows.github.io/